# NEHotspotNetwork fetchCurrent signal strange why always zero?

Tags: swift, nehotspothelper

When I call `fetchCurrent` on `NEHotspotNetwork`, I am able to correctly retrieve the SSID and other information, but why do I always receive zero as the signal strength value?

```
        NEHotspotNetwork.fetchCurrent(completionHandler: { currentNetwork in
            result(currentNetwork?.signalStrength);
        })
```

I saw a lot of questions and answers about this but I can't figure out why is that.